# How to hide any pop up console triggered while running a script in main console using PYTHON

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, cmd, hide, command-prompt

I am running a python script to install an exe which has no silent switch, so once the script is triggered it will pop up a new console showing the progress for the installation.

How do i **hide this new console** or make it run in background using either **python/powershell** and **close it once done**.

**Python code:**

```
p = subprocess.Popen(r'path\file.exe --path="path"', shell=True)
```

OS: **Windows**

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe [minimize](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25466795/503046) installer's window could work?

Comment: Why do you use `shell=True`? This results in starting `%ComSpec% /c path\file.exe --path="path"`, i.e. in running `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c path\file.exe --path="path"`. There is no need to run Windows command processor `cmd.exe` to run an executable from within a Python script. So I strongly recommend not using `shell=True` respectively use `shell=False` to run `path\file.exe` directly without `cmd.exe`.

Comment: @Mofi ill look into it. Btw this doesn't answer my question, the issue is my exe does not have a silent switch so when the python script is triggered the exe pops up a new console showing the installation progress- i want this console to run in background or hide this new console

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows you can save the file with a `.pyw` extension to prevent a DOS console from popping up to display the output

Comment: Thanks for your immediate answer, but will executing .pyw using pythonw.exe supress any number of new console that might be triggered from the main script.