# How to minimize all non active windows using python code?

Tags: python

Is there any way to minimize all non active windows using python, leaving the active windows.

Comment: You can start from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25466795/how-to-minimize-a-specific-window-in-python), take a look to win32gui, win32con

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this based on your exact purpose. (Please clarify what exactly you want to do)

However in general these modules are useful for such tasks:
PyAutoGUI; https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/
Win32gui; https://pypi.org/project/win32gui/

Comment: Also check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25466795/how-to-minimize-a-specific-window-in-python

Comment: yeah, the PyAutoGUI helped me solve my problem.

Comment: Glad that I could be of help.